# Wrapping Python cProfile runctx API to parameterize runs with anything anywhere

Tags: python, import, profiling, python-importlib

Using Python 3.7.2,

I'm trying to wrap `cProfile.runctx()` into a separate module such as `util.profile_runs()` from my main module `mymain.py` to profile functions in the main module. This requires importing `mymain.py` in `util.profile_runs()`.

However, I couldn't get `importlib` working with the following code in `util.py`:

```
import cProfile as profile
import importlib.util
from os.path import basename, splitext
from pprint import pprint
import pstats
import sys

def profile_runs(funcname, modulefile, nruns=5):
    importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES.append('')
    module_name = splitext(basename(modulefile))[0]
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, modulefile)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    # if desired: importlib.machinery.SOURCE_SUFFIXES.pop()

    pprint(dir(module))

    for i in range(nruns):
        filename = 'profile_{}_{}.stats'.format(funcname, i)
        profile.runctx('print({}, {}.{}())'.format(i, module_name, funcname), globals(), locals(), filename)

    # Read all 5 stats files into a single object
    stats = pstats.Stats('profile_stats_0.stats')

    for i in range(1, nruns):
        stats.add('profile_{}_{}.stats'.format(funcname, i))

    # Clean up filenames for the report
    stats.strip_dirs()

    # Sort the statistics by the cumulative time spent
    # in the function
    stats.sort_stats('cumulative')
    stats.print_stats()
```

and `mymain.py`:

```
import util

def func_to_profile()
    print('running func_to_profile')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    util.profile_runs('funct_to_profile')
```

The `pprint(dir(module))` line outputs correct info of the module, but the `.runctx` call keeps saying:

```
NameError: name 'mymain' is not defined
```

It works if I explicitly `import mymain` in the `util.profile_runs()` code.
Is it a bad idea to profile this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: Just insert `import module_name;` in the run string, like this:

```
profile.runctx('import {};print({}, {}.{}())'.format(module_name, i, module_name, funcname), globals(), locals(), filename)
```

and get rid of the whole `importlib` dance.